# Do town portals stay in place if you leave town through other means?

Tags: torchlight

I came back from floor 9 of the Shadow Vault through a town portal that I left next to a fishing hole. However, after doing my business in town, I forgot the town portal was there, and I re-entered the Shadow Vault through the regular entrance in the shrine.

I'm currently on floor 3. If I go back to town, will my portal to level 9 still be there? I don't feel like going all the way down to level 9 to find my fishing hole, but I'm not sure if going back up will be worth my time either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Town portals will stay in place as long as you don't make a new one.  So to keep your portal on floor 9, you'll have to walk back to town.